# Filing category for I-485 spouse

Tags: immigration

I am applying (Adjust. of Status; [**I-485**](https://www.uscis.gov/i-485)) as a derivative applicant. My spouse has an approved I-140 (National Interest Waiver).

I was wondering as a derivative applicant, which of the options (i.e., 1.a through 1.g) provided in [**Part 2 of I-485 Revised form**](https://www.uscis.gov/i-485) should I choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a derivative beneficiary, you would choose the same category as the principal beneficiary, which in this case, is the first checkbox under "1.b. Employment-based", which says "Alien worker, Form I-140".

Comment: @rnorouzian: The timeframe is normal. USPS "priority mail" is not express mail so should have been sent to the PO box and not the other address, but if it got delivered it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @morouzian: No, an I-864 Affidavit of Support is not necessary for employment-based categories unless the petitioning company is at least 5% owned by a relative of the immigrant.